# UPDATE FROM in SQL with matching key

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

How can I `UPDATE FROM` in SQL? I want to copy the `FamilyID` from my `FamilyGuardian` table:

**dbo.FamilyGuardian**

```
PupilID   FamilyID    GuardianID
---------------------------------
1         100002      555
2         100003      556
3         100004      557
4         100005      558
5         100006      559
6         100007      1146
7         100008      561
8         100009      562
9         100010      563
10        100011      564
```

Into the Guardians table where `GuardianID` is equal.

**dbo.Guardians**

```
GuardianID  Name        FamilyID
---------------------------------
555         Smith       NULL
556         Patel       NULL
557         Andrews     NULL
558         Brown       NULL
559         Abdul       NULL
```

**dbo.Guardians after `INSERT FROM`**

```
GuardianID  Name        FamilyID
--------------------------------
555         Smith       100002
556         Patel       100003
557         Andrews     100004
558         Brown       100005
559         Abdul       100006
```

Comment: Hi Alex, you accepted one answer, this is great, but I feel myself obliged to point out, that all upvoted answers at the moment are either wrong or dangerous. The accepted answer will set your `FamilyID` unpredictably if there might be more than one row per `GuardianID` in `FamilyGuardian`. If you can be sure, that this never will be, your table's design is wrong. And if this might be, your table's design is wrong too...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to use an **UPDATE** query

```
UPDATE T1
SET T1.FamiltyID = T2.FamilyID
FROM dbo.Guardians AS T1 INNER JOIN dbo.FamilyGuardian AS T2
ON T1.GuardianID = T2.GuardianID
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as `INSERT FROM` - you're looking for `UPDATE`, not `INSERT`:

```
Update  G
Set     FamilyId = F.FamilyId
From    FamilyGuardian  F
Join    Guardian        G   On  G.GuardianId = F.GuardianId
```

Answer (score 1):

You might use an *updateable CTE* for this

```
WITH UpdateableCTE AS
(
    SELECT g.FamilyID
          ,fg.FamilyID AS newValue
    FROM dbo.Guardians AS g
    INNER JOIN dbo.FamilyGuardian AS fg ON g.GuardianID=fg.GuardianID
)
UPDATE UpdateableCTE SET FamilyID=newValue;
```

But you must be aware, that this design is - uhm - weak...

What would happen if one Guard is responsible for more than one family? What happens, if the information on one side changes, but the other side does not change?

I think, this **should not get into a physically defined column** at all. This should be taken with a `JOIN` whenever you read this data.

Answer (score 1):

you mean an UPDATE, not an INSERT, right?

In that case you should use an structue like:

```
UPDATE dbo.Guardians
SET FamilyID = (SELECT DISTINCT FamilyID FROM dbo.FamilyGuardian fg WHERE fg.GuardianID  = GuardianID )
```

Notice that the DISTINCT is only necessary when there are more than 1 familyId per guardianId.

Comment: Instead of `DISTINCT` you wanted to place `TOP 1`. Anyway one must be aware, that this design has severe issues if more than one corresponding row in `FamilyGuard` is possible. All answers would return rather unpredictably, yours would run into an exception...

Comment: Why would it throw an exception?

Comment: Simply because `SELECT DISTINCT` will surpress non-unique rows (in other words: will return unique), but it will not return **one single row** if there are more of them. You write *more than 1 familyId per guardianId*. Exactly in this case you'd get an error, because assigning a value with a sub-select `SET x=(subselect)` **must** return one single column in one single row (in other words: scalar).

Comment: Off course, thank you. I didn't put the `TOP 1`, because there is no such instruction in postgres, and I tried to make the response more general, though I made a mistake.